# Entity Framework behavior with Whitespaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a scenario where I need to allow empty duplicates and reject other kinds of duplicates so I am checking for existing records before inserting a new one using the following query.

```
this.dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefault(t =>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(newRecord.Name) && t.Name.Trim().Equals(newRecord.Name.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

The thing is that when I have data like following:

```
oldRecord.Name="   "

newRecord.Name="   "
```

The above query returns Null. which is weird because

1. result of `!string.IsNullOrEmpty("   ")` is true
2. result of `"   ".Trim().Equals("   ".Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` is true

So the above query should give me results.

Any idea why I am getting this behavior? and will the above query be evaluated client side?

Comment: Oh you're right, your bullet points don't match your query. Can you log and see what SQL this generates? I do think this will be evaluated on the client side though, not sure how the query builder builds `newRecord.Name.Trim()`.

Comment: Is it possible not to allow spaces in your db? You can always trim the spaces from specific properties inside the modelbuilder with the .HasConversion extension.

Answer (score 0):

For that there's another method called `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, which has "broader" application and works as you expect:

```
var whiteSpaceStrings = new string[]
{
    "   ", // some spaces
    "           ", // some tabs
    string.Empty, // empty
    "", // empty
};
foreach (var str in whiteSpaceStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str));
}
```

It prints all `true` :)

Answering your doubts: `IsNullOrEmpty` checks if string is `null` or empty - but empty string is string without any character. And whitespace (any) is character itself :)

Comment: Please read the query, IsNullOrEmpty has ! before it. this is why I asked this question, since whitespace is a character then the query should return results